# Subtracting the revenue value for the earliest date minus the latest date in redshift sql

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

| account name | year | revenue |
| --- | --- | --- |
| abc | 2006 | 1000 |
| abc | 2007 | 2000 |
| abc | 2008 | 5000 |

Hello everyone,
So I am trying to find a way to subtract the revenue for the latest year for a given account name to the earliest year found in a dataset.

For example in the above table

the latest year for abc -> 2008
the  earliest year for abc -> 2006,

I can't hardcode the years in the code, I don't know what the years would be.

So, I want to get something like this

| account name | subtracted revenue |
| --- | --- |
| abc | 4000 |

I wish I could share some code but I have no idea how to proceed. I was thinking of using windowing function, but don't know how to apply it in this scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is something that I tried, just check if this is any helpful

````
insert into revenue
select * from
(select 'abc' as accountname, 2006 as year, 1000 as revenue union 
select 'abc' as accountname, 2007 as year, 2000 as revenue union 
select 'abc' as accountname, 2008 as year, 5000 as revenue union 
select 'def' as accountname, 2004 as year, 1000 as revenue union 
select 'def' as accountname, 2006 as year, 3000 as revenue union 
select 'xyz' as accountname, 2005 as year, 5000 as revenue 
) as a

select accountname
, sum(case when yearname ='maxyear' then revenue else 0 end) - sum(case when yearname ='minyear' then revenue else 0 end) subtractedrevenue
from 
(select * 
, case when min(year)over(partition by accountname order by accountname) = max(year)over(partition by accountname order by accountname) then 'maxyear' 
when year = min(year)over(partition by accountname order by accountname) then 'minyear' 
 when year= max(year)over(partition by accountname order by accountname) then 'maxyear'
else '' end yearname
from revenue
) as a 
where yearname<>''
group by accountname```
````

Comment: Hey, This works! Thanks! I don't think order by is required though!

Comment: Do you have any idea if we want to select the second highest year? Sorry for asking so many questions

Comment: yeah,.. just update this year= max(year)over(partition by accountname order by accountname) , you can get that

Comment: Can you let me know how to do that, right now I am using a very complex logic, which I don't think is product suitable 
```
where date_cmp(to_date(DATE_PART_YEAR(to_date(fiscal_year, 'YYYY')), 'YYYY'), to_date(DATE_PART_YEAR(current_date),'YYYY')) <>0 
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are you asking just to pull the second highest year, or difference in revenue from first to second highest year?

Comment: second highest year

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions:

```
select account_name,
       sum(case when seqnum_desc = 1 then revenue else - revenue end)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by account_name order by year) as seqnum_asc,
             row_number() over (partition by account_name order by year desc) as seqnum_desc
      from t
     ) t
where 1 in (seqnum_asc, seqnum_desc)
group by account_name;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=3c6b0416b86f769f99af428917a45e86) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Hi This logic is adding not subtracting.

Comment: but I feel the logic looks good, can you please recheck it, it would be of great help!

Comment: @ParasPandey. . . Do you have `- revenue` for the `else` clause?

Comment: Yes, I am using it in the else clause, for some reason it is still adding. I have also tried doing something like -1*revenue and created my own dummy data with a similar result

Comment: @ParasPandey . . . That is quite strange.  Something seems wrong.

Comment: You can actually use an online sql editor and type the code as well. I did it with dummy data and got the same result.

https://www.jdoodle.com/execute-sql-online/

Comment: @ParasPandey . . . Funny that it even ran.  There was a typo in the `case` expression.  I added a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Hi Gordon, Thank you for the answer. This works now. Also one quick question. Do you know how I could get to subtract it with the earliest year with the second highest year? You can edit the original answer. I was trying to fiddle with it but could not get the final result.

Comment: @ParasPandey . . . You accepted another answer.  I would suggest that you ask a new question.